# NPM can't install any package behind proxy

Tags: npm, proxy

I am behind a business proxy and when I do `npm i -g npm` to update my npm it respond :

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SLL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknow protocol:openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:825:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Moaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-23T08_15_17_061Z-debug.log
```

Here is the npm config:

```
proxy=http://proxy.###.intra:8080/
https-proxy=https://proxy.###.intra:8080/
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Any help would be appreciate :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add proxy using command line also:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8181
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

You can then check settings using:

```
npm config ls -l | grep prox
```

Sometimes, the SSL also create problem, you can run the following:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Check your proxy port, the http and https proxy port should be different.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, what is the output for "npm config ls -l | grep prox"

Comment: https-proxy=https://proxy.company.intra:8080
proxy=http://proxy.company.intra:8080
;https-proxy = null (overidden)
;proxy= null (overidden)

Comment: Can you check your https proxy port? Your http and https proxy port need to be different.

Comment: No, I found that my company changed the URL of my proxy. I changed it and now HTTP is on 80 and HTTPS on 443 but it still not working. :/

Comment: The same as the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error can be occur because of proxy you use for network. Even you add proxy settings to your PC that is not enough for work with npm. So you have to config proxy setting manually to work with npm.

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy_name:port
```

Here username is the user name you use to connect network and password is its password. Proxy name is the name of proxy or connection that you use in PC. and port is the proxy runnig port in your PC, like 8080.

Answer (score -2):

The real problem was with creation of symlinks containing ../

Add this in command line to update your npm config :

```
npm config set bin-links false
```

Comment: This is really bad advice.
This will disable npm to create .bin folder in /node_modules folder. This will prevent you to run npm packages from command line. 
It has nothing common with proxy.